# puppet - ruby template - ip address from a generated interface name

Tags: templates, puppet, embedded-ruby

I have a following ruby template

```
interface <%= @interface %>
  state <%= @state %>
  priority <%= @priority %>

  virtual_router_id 1
  unicast_src_ip <%= @ipaddress_interface %>
```

at unicast_src_ip I would add the @interface-s ip address.
the interface name is dynamic.
So if I get eth0 in @interface the @ipadress_interface should be the ip of eth0 (@ipaddress_eth0).
IF I predefine the name of the NIC like nic01. The @ipadress_nic01 works like a charm. But unfortunately I know the if name only when the puppet runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access dynamically-determined variables by using [the `scope` object](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/lang_template_erb.html#scope-variable-or-scope-lookupvar-variable) exposed to ERB scriptlets.  It takes the name of the variable you want to access as a string, which can be computed at runtime in any of the ways that Ruby affords.  Example:

```
  unicast_src_ip <%= scope["ipaddress_#{@interface}"] %>
```